# Allow users to upload HD video to youtube without wifi connection?

Tags: android, iphone, youtube

I am about to build a large ios/android app but before I do I need to know if it is possible for users to upload video to youtube in high definition without a wifi connection. I will likely keep video max size to 30 seconds and will require HD quality. These files are typically 20M-40M from an iphone (as far as I understand) and there will likely be dozens to a hundred or so users uploading simultaneously all to the company's youtube channel. I was just wondering if I could get some advice on whether or not to attempt to include this feature in our app, or perhaps get some thoughts on what will happen if I do.

Comment: does anyone have experience with this?